# Python RPC over TCP library

Tags: library, python, json

I'm looking for a python library that allows me to create an RPC client/server.

I need it to work directly with TCP (no HTTP).

It would also be nice for it to provide a class to do "proxying" for me, but I can also implement on my own.

Another advantage is if exceptions can be are thrown back to the client.

One last thing -  I also prefer human readable transfer formats (json, yaml)

Thanks in advance